# "Cartograph" font has too much spacing

Tags: fonts

[image: cartograph]

This is what happened when I set my default font to a new font I bought called [Cartograph](https://connary.com/cartograph.html). Looks cool, but I'm not sure I could get used to it. Anyone know what might have happened? It's an otf font. Looks normal in LibreWrite and gedit, BTW. Here's the init entry

```lisp
'(default 
    ((t (:inherit nil 
         :stipple nil 
         :inverse-video nil 
         :box nil 
         :strike-through nil 
         :overline nil 
         :underline nil 
         :slant normal 
         :weight normal 
         :height 143 
         :width normal 
         :foundry "UKWN" 
         :family "Cartograph CF"))))
```

Comment: just a guess, but what does it look like if you only specify the font, and none of the other details (weight, height etc)? If the spacing is ok with that, you'll know something in your detailed settings is causing the problem

Comment: Didn't help. I took out everything but `:family "Cartograph CF`.

Comment: This looks similar to https://github.com/googlefonts/Inconsolata/issues/42. Are you using a version of Emacs older than 27.1?

Comment: I'm on 27.1. Would it make a difference to recompile --with-cairo?

Comment: Before trying to recompile you may check the output of `M-x set-variable RET eval-expression-print-length RET nil RET` `M-: (font-info (font-at 1)) RET` on a non empty buffer. There should be an array of numbers somewhere. The last two values should be in the surroundings of your font size, 14. If it's much larger than that, then it's more likely that your issue is related to the one with Inconsolata and that compiling with Cairo support will solve it.

Comment: (Don't take my word for it, I'm at the limit of my knowledge about fonts in Emacs; for some references, see https://github.com/googlefonts/Inconsolata/issues/42#issuecomment-573386767 and the following messages, and the doc string of `font-info`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through [this](https://github.com/googlefonts/Inconsolata/issues/42#issuecomment-573386767) and following the advice of Arch Stanton in the above comments -- although I didn't understand his instructions

> There should be an array of numbers somewhere. The last two values
> should be in the surroundings of your font size, 14.

I did recompile Emacs 27.1 with cairo

```
./configure --with-cairo
```

and the problem is solved.